# I'm not able to get data-id (dynamic HTML. in the last left position) in ajax using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

This is view code.
The first time works properly. In dynamic HTML, not able to get data-id '(onclick event)' in js.
I would like to when I'll add any user tree work infinitely.
when we click any user via ajax get the child from ajax this is the concept basically.
but I'm unable to get data-id in the next level via ajax.

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <div class="member-view-box">
              <div class="member-image">
                  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg" title="<?php echo $tree[0]->fname . " " . $tree[0]->lname ?>" alt="Member">
                  <div class="member-details">
                      <small><?php echo $tree[0]->partner_id; ?></small>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </a>
      <ul class="active">
          <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="<?php echo $tree[1]->branch_left; ?>">
                  <div class="member-view-box">
                      <div class="member-image">
                          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg" title="<?php echo $tree[1]->fname . " " . $tree[1]->lname ?>" alt="Member">
                          <div class="member-details">
                              <small><?php echo $tree[1]->partner_id; ?></small>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </a>
              <ul id="<?php echo $tree[1]->branch_left; ?>"></ul>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="<?php echo $tree[1]->branch_right; ?>">
                  <div class="member-view-box">
                      <div class="member-image">
                          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg" title="<?php echo $tree[2]->fname . " " . $tree[2]->lname ?>" alt="Member">
                          <div class="member-details">
                              <small><?php echo $tree[2]->partner_id; ?></small>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </a>
              <ul id="<?php echo $tree[1]->branch_right; ?>"></ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

--------------------------
This is controller
    public function get_tree_by_ajax()
    {
        $this->Dashboard_m->get_tree_by_ajax($_POST);
    }

----------------------------
This is model code.



 public function get_tree_by_ajax()
    {
        $pid = $this->input->post('pid');
        if (!empty($pid)) {
            $data = $this->db
                ->get_where('tree', ['v_id' => $pid])
                ->row();
            $arr = array(
                '0' => $data->branch_left,
                '1' => $data->branch_right,
            );

            if (!empty($arr && $data)) {

                foreach ($arr as $val) {
                    $tree = $this->db
                        ->select('t1.*,t2.*')
                        ->from('vendor t1')
                        ->join('tree t2', 't2.v_id=t1.vid', 'LEFT')
                        ->where(['t1.vid' => $val])
                        ->order_by('vid', 'ASC')
                        ->limit(3)
                        ->get()
                        ->result();
                    $arr1[] = $tree;
                }
                // print_r($arr1);
                // exit;
                $x = $arr1[0];
                $y = $arr1[1];
                if (!empty($data->branch_left) && !empty($data->branch_right)) {
                    echo "
                <ul class='active'>
                    <li>
                        <a href='javascript:void(0);' data-id='" . $x[0]->v_id . "'>
                            <div class='member-view-box'>
                                <div class='member-image'>
                                    <img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg' title='" . $x[0]->fname . $x[0]->lname . "' alt='Member'>
                                    <div class='member-details'>
                                        <small>" . $x[0]->partner_id . "</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul id='" . $x[0]->v_id . "'></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='javascript:void(0);' data-id='" . $y[0]->v_id . "'>
                            <div class='member-view-box'>
                                <div class='member-image'>
                                    <img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg' title='" . $y[0]->fname . $y[0]->lname . "' alt='Member'>
                                    <div class='member-details'>
                                        <small>" . $y[0]->partner_id . "</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul id='" . $y[0]->v_id . "'></ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            ";
                } elseif (!empty($data->branch_left)) {
                    echo "
                <ul class='active'>
                    <li>
                        <a href='javascript:void(0);' data-id='" . $x[0]->v_id . "'>
                            <div class='member-view-box'>
                                <div class='member-image'>
                                    <img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg' title='" . $x[0]->fname . $x[0]->lname . "' alt='Member'>
                                    <div class='member-details'>
                                        <small>" . $x[0]->partner_id . "</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul id='" . $x[0]->v_id . "'></ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            ";
                } elseif (!empty($data->branch_right)) {
                    echo "
                <ul class='active'>
                   
                    <li>
                        <a href='javascript:void(0);' data-id='" . $y[0]->v_id . "'>
                            <div class='member-view-box'>
                                <div class='member-image'>
                                    <img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg' title='" . $y[0]->fname . $y[0]->lname . "' alt='Member'>
                                    <div class='member-details'>
                                        <small>" . $y[0]->partner_id . "</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul id='" . $y[0]->v_id . "'></ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            ";
                } else {
                    echo 'not';
                }
            }
        }
    }

--------------------------
this is ajax


<script>
    $("a").click(function() {
        var pid = $(this).data("id");
        alert(pid);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>get-tree-data",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                pid: pid
            },
            success: function(result) {
                if (result == 'not') {
                    alert('No partner here !!');
                } else {
                    $("#" + pid).html(result);
                }


                console.log("Response======>" + result);
                // alert(result);


            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: wrap you click event in a function lets say click_me(){$("a).click(...)}; then call click_me() in ajax succes (after the DOM update, eventually with a little timeout)) , that should do it....

Comment: Whenever I click on the link, the DOM gets updated. Then when I click on the links below, there is no response and no error giving